# Open a text file with accents in python

Tags: python, utf-8

I try to open a text file in French with Python 2.7. I used the command

```
f=open('textfr','r')
```

but when I use

```
f.read()
```

I lose accented characters: I get `u"J'\xc3\xa9tais \xc3\xa0` Paris instead of `J'étais à` Paris, etc..

when in linux terminal, I do

```
file -i textfr
```

I get

```
charset=utf-8
```

so I do not understand...

Comment: have you tried print f.read()?

Answer (score 11):

You need to specify the charset.

```
f = io.open('textfr', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Yes, it does. It must, by definition.

Comment: @Mustafa: When you say "I get `J'\xc3\xa9tais \xc3\xa0 Paris`" are you "get"-ting it by using the `print` statement to a terminal, or evaluating the contents of a variable in an interactive Python session?  If you are using a terminal, how is it configured?  (for *nix style hosts, what is your `TERM` env var set to)

Comment: I get it when I enter f.read() in the spyder IDE, or in the python ide launched from the terminal of ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What's the 'r'?

Answer (score 3):

By default, files are read/written using the system default text encoding, as can be found
in `sys.getdefaultencoding()` . On most machines, this is set to `utf-8` . but some of machines like yours doesn't use `utf-8` you can use a proper encoding for your file , or use `utf-8` that is a universal encoding :

in python 3 :

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
         #do stuff
```

in python 2 you can use `codecs.open()`:

```
import codecs
f=codecs.open ('somefile.txt', 'rt', encoding='utf-8').read()
```

Comment: `open()` in 2.x doesn't have an `encoding` argument.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams oh, yep ,i'll add this to answer

Answer (score 1):

use [codecs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) instead of standard `open` so

```
import codecs
codecs.open('textfr','r', 'utf-8')
```

Comment: thanks, but it does not work...so maybe the problem is elsewhere